# WSL 2 : How to run project under wsl partition throught Pycharm?

Tags: python, odoo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to run my Odoo 13 located in my WSL 2 (ubuntu 20.04) with Pycharm,
I configured everything but when I clicked the run button, I got this error : **/bin/bash: line 0: cd: \wsl$Ubuntu-20.04optodoo13: No such file or directory**
Here are some print screens of my configuration :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![Interpreters configuration][2]][2]

I want to point out that the pycharm is installed in windows environment and the odoo folders are inside wsl.

PS : OMG guys, can you see the images that i uploaded?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x6B7.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOybG.png

Comment: If you don't mind switching IDE, you can easily setup for WSL with vscode. You only need to install WSL extension and run `code .` inside WSL.

Comment: @Pyae, I use Pycharm pro and wanna stick with it, or I will lose my money. I tested the visual code but don't know to configure multiple "run" (as I always use in pycharm) on it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workarround, I move the project directories to windows partition.